# Is it more secure to use VPN client?

Tags: security, seed, keylogger

As I am always afraid of keylogger and viruses "seeing" me tipping in the seed into my wallet I wonder if it may be more secure if I use a VPN tunnel to go into the internet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to IOTA at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A VPN don't protect you about a keylogger.

I don't see a useful case to use a vpn to protect your seed.

If you fear keylogger, [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or any other Virtualmachine Software can help you.
Also a combination of Copy/Paste and writing can prevent a keylogger to get your full seed.

Feel free to read somethings about VPN [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/133680/htg-explains-what-is-a-vpn/).